# Program to generate prime numbers, error: "Stack overflow"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda

I have program, which generate prime numbers in CUDA and program crash on line 138:

```
cudaMemcpy(gpudata, data, sizeof(int)*MAXSIZE, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

---

I got error "Stack overflow" for that line.

Can you tell me how can I fix it?

```
#define MAXSIZE 250000

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>  //Writing to files
#include <chrono>   //Keep track of time
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
// to remove intellisense highlighting
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>
#ifndef __CUDACC__
#define __CUDACC__
#endif
#include <algorithm>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

using namespace std::chrono;

int data[MAXSIZE];
//Main CUDA kernel implementing Sieve of Eratosthenes
__global__ static void CUDASieve(int *num, int range, int bNum, int tNum) {
    const int threadId = threadIdx.x;
    const int blockId = blockIdx.x;
    int tmp = blockId * tNum + threadId;
    while (tmp < range) {
        int i = 1;
        while (((2 * tmp + 3)*i + tmp + 1) < MAXSIZE) {
            num[(2 * tmp + 3)*i + tmp + 1] = 0;
            i++;
        }
        tmp += bNum * tNum;
    }
}
void CUDAFilter(int *number, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        number[i] = 2 * i + 1;
    number[0] = 2;
}

void reportTime(const char* msg, steady_clock::duration span) {
    auto ms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(span);
    std::cout << msg << ms.count() << " millisecs" << std::endl;
}

void CPUgenPrime(uint64_t range, bool mode, std::ofstream &fileOut) {
    //Start the clock
    steady_clock::time_point ts, te;
    ts = steady_clock::now();
    fileOut << "\nCPU version\n" << "\nCPU version generating from range (0" << "~" << range << ")\n\n";
    //Keep track of results
    uint64_t count = 0;
    //Outer loop
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < range; i++)
        //Inner loop
        for (uint64_t j = 2; j*j <= i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0)
                break;
            else if (j + 1 > sqrt(i)) {
                //User wants to see output on screen
                if (mode) {
                    std::cout << std::fixed << i << "\t";
                    fileOut << std::fixed << i << "\t";
                    count++;
                }
                //Just write to file if mode is 0
                else
                {
                    fileOut << std::fixed << i << "\t";
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    //Stop the clock
    te = steady_clock::now();

    std::cout << "\n\nTotal number of primes: " << count << std::endl;
    reportTime("\nCPU Program Completed in ", te - ts);

    fileOut << "\n\nTotal number of primes: " << count << std::endl;

    std::cout << "A log file with the current date/time has been placed in the program directory.\n";
    std::cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
}

std::ofstream fileInit() {
    //Get current date and time
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    char buffer[80];
    time(&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);

    //Format in Year-Month-Day_Hour_Minute_Seconds
    strftime(buffer, 80, "%y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S", timeinfo);
    std::string dateTime(buffer);

    //File handles
    std::ofstream fileOut;
    fileOut.open("GenPrime_out_" + dateTime + ".txt");
    return fileOut;
}

int setupRange(int range) {
    if (range == 0) {
        std::cout << "[2/3] Please choose the range(3 ~ 500,000): \n";
        std::cin >> range;

        //Error checking
        if (range > 2 && range <= 500000) {
            return range;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Invalid input for range, value set to default 500,000\n";
            return 500000;
        }
    }
    else return range;
}

//Array of MAXSIZE is created and filled with prime numbers, where [i]
//is the prime int and the rest is padded with 0's
//Example: cpudata[i] = {0,1,0,3,0,5,0,7,0,0,0,11,0,0,0...}
void justDoIt(int range, bool mode, std::ofstream& fileOut) {
    //Output to file
    fileOut << "CUDA Multithreading Sieve of Eratosthenes\n" << "CUDA Multithreading generating from range (0" << "~" << range << ")\n\n";

    //Filter out even numbers to simplify calculation
    CUDAFilter(data, (range / 2) + 1);

    //Initialize arrays
    int *gpudata;
    int cpudata[MAXSIZE];

    //Allocate memory
    cudaMalloc((void**)&gpudata, sizeof(int)*MAXSIZE);

    //Copy to GPU
    cudaMemcpy(gpudata, data, sizeof(int)*MAXSIZE, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    //Maximum threads per block for CUDA 5.2 is 1024
    int bNum = 96, tNum = 1024;

    //Start the clock
    steady_clock::time_point ts, te;
    ts = steady_clock::now();

    //Kernel call on the GPU
    CUDASieve << <bNum, tNum, 0 >> > (gpudata, range, bNum, tNum);

    //Synchronize the device and the host
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    //Copy from GPU back onto host
    cudaMemcpy(&cpudata, gpudata, sizeof(int)*MAXSIZE, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    //Free the memory on the GPU
    cudaFree(gpudata);

    //Reset the device for easy profiling
    cudaDeviceReset();

    //Stop the clock
    te = steady_clock::now();

    //Display on screen
    if (mode == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAXSIZE; i++) {
            if (cpudata[i] != 0)
                printf("%d\t", cpudata[i]);
        }
    }
    //Count number of primes
    int count = std::count_if(cpudata, cpudata + MAXSIZE, [](int i) { return i; });
    std::cout << "\n\nTotal number of primes: " << count - 2 << std::endl;

    //Write to file
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXSIZE; i++) {
        if (cpudata[i] != 0) {
            fileOut << cpudata[i] << "\t";
        }
    }
    //Show the amount of time 
    reportTime("GPU Program Completed in ", te - ts);
    fileOut << "\n\nTotal number of primes: " << count - 2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "A log file with the current date/time has been placed in the program directory.\n";
    std::cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
}

void menu(int range, bool mode, std::ofstream& fileOut) {
    std::cout << "[3/3] Please select the version of the program you want to run\n"
        << "1. [*****]  CUDA Multithreading Sieve of Eratosthenes version\n"
        << "2. [***]    Simple CPU version\n"
        << "3. [**] Run both versions\n"
        << "0. Quit\n"
        << "Option: ";
    int mainMenuOption;
    std::cin >> mainMenuOption; //Accept user input
    switch (mainMenuOption) {
    case 0: // User wants to exit
        std::cout << "Thank you for testing our program :)\n"
            << "Fork us @ https://github.com/bbershadsky/" << std::endl;
        break;
    case 1:
        std::cout << "CUDA Multithreading generating from range (0" << "~" << range << ")\n";
        std::cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
        justDoIt(range, mode, fileOut);

        //Close the file handle
        fileOut.close();
        break;
    case 2:
        std::cout << "CPU version generating from range (0" << "~" << range << ")\n";
        std::cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
        CPUgenPrime(range, mode, fileOut);

        //Close the file handle
        fileOut.close();
        break;
    case 3:
        std::cout << "Running all available options\n";
        justDoIt(range, mode, fileOut);
        CPUgenPrime(range, mode, fileOut);

        //Close the file handle
        fileOut.close();
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "[Invalid option. Only integers 0-3 are allowed]\n";
        menu(range, mode, fileOut);
        break;
    }
}

void setupScreenMode(int range) {
    std::cout << "***Team /dev/null GPU610 PRIME NUMBER GENERATOR v3.5***\n"
        << "[1/3] Would you like to see the output on screen?\n"
        << "0 = NO, write to file only\n"
        << "1 = YES, display on screen\n"
        << "Show on screen?: ";
    int mode = 1;
    std::cin >> mode;

    //Initialize file handle
    std::ofstream fileOut = fileInit();

    if (mode == 0) {
        std::cout << "***Writing output to file only***\n\n";
        range = setupRange(range);
        menu(range, mode, fileOut);
    }

    else if (mode == 1) {
        std::cout << "***Outputting results on screen***\n\n";
        range = setupRange(range);
        menu(range, mode, fileOut);
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "[Invalid option selected, default option 0 (output to screen) selected]\n\n";
        range = setupRange(range);
        menu(range, 1, fileOut);
    }
}

//Initialize value to be used in the program using command line arguments
int initRuntimeValue(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    //Save runtime parameter into local variable, if provided
    int range = 500000;
    if (argc == 1) {
        std::cout << "[No command line parameters provided]\n\n";
        return 0;
    }
    if (argc == 2)
        range = std::atoi(argv[1]);
    if (range > 2 && range < 500000)
        return range;
    else {
        std::cout << "[Bad input for range parameter (must be <= 500,000)]\n"
            << "Range has been set to 500,000\n";
        return range = 500000;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    //Grab the command line arguments
    int range = initRuntimeValue(argc, argv);

    //Prompt user for mode (verbose or silent)
    setupScreenMode(range);
    std::cout << "Thank you for testing our program :)\n"
        << "Fork us @ https://github.com/bbershadsky/" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

/*
CHANGELOG
v1.0 - Generating from simple double loop
v1.0.1 - Command line parameter input
v1.1 - Nicer output format and error feedback
v1.2 - Full 64 bit integer compatibility
v1.3 - Multithreading and CUDA implemented
v2.0 - Completely rewrote program to include menu and multiple run parameters
v3.0 - Full rewrite of CUDAGenPrime to use CUDASieve of Eratosthenes, and initRuntimeValues
v3.1 - Moved new CUDAGenPrime to separate function justDoIt(range);
v3.2 - Reorganized main() into simpler blocks for easier readability and efficiency
v3.3 - Moved most control blocks over to the menu() for easier modification
v3.3.1 - Removed a bunch of unused includes
v3.4 - Successfully fixed file output and implemented count
v3.5 - Final version with usability and performance upgrades
*/
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a [mcve] to me. Surely you can reduce it further.

Comment: Your question cannot be deleted by you because of an upvoted answer. Rather than defacing your question, and reaping the bucket of downvotes that usually comes with that, flag the question and ask for moderator intervention. Be explicit.

Answer (score 3):

It may have something to do with putting an array of of 250000 ints on the stack:

```
int cpudata[MAXSIZE];
```

You should put large arrays on the heap.

```
int* cpudata = new int[MAXSIZE];
```

and don't forget to delete when you're done.

```
delete [] cpudata;
```

Comment: hmpf. `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: Once you make the change in this answer, this will be broken: `cudaMemcpy(&cpudata,`; remove the ampersand.  The name of an array nicely decays to a pointer, and the address of an array does the same - decays to a pointer to the array data.  However when you convert to an actual pointer as suggested in this answer, the `&cpudata` does not mean the same thing anymore.  (The ampersand was not really necessary even with the original array usage.)